# Hitch failed to reload?

Tags: sni

My site suddenly failed to load Hitch.

And I used command /usr/sbin/hitch --config /etc/hitch/hitch.conf

It showed

Warning: SNI name 'froninail.com' from '/etc/letsencrypt/live/froninail.com/hitch-bundle.pem' overridden by '/etc/letsencrypt/live/froninail.com/hitch-bundle.pem'

Warning: SNI name 'www.froninail.com' from '/etc/letsencrypt/live/froninail.com/hitch-bundle.pem' overridden by '/etc/letsencrypt/live/froninail.com/hitch-bundle.pem'

Can you help me fix on this?

I don't find the solution to fix it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In order for people to help you, more information is required, can you please add the content of `/etc/hitch/hitch.conf`. Also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64277891/ for possible solution to your problem.